# Can't acces to address ip with FTP port (21) by telnet

Tags: windows, ftp, telnet

I try to use FTP server on Windows Server 2012 and in the configuration i try to test the port (21) on a client machine by doing the command ms dos:

```
telnet 192.168.0.2 21
```

I have installed the telnet on my windows client and i have installed also the IIS and FTP service on windows 2012 and i checked that the FTP services is autorized by the firwall and all are good.

But at every time , when i try to do : telnet 192.168.0.2 21  + enter it told me that is impossible to do the connexion on the port 21.

in the config of the firewall

[image]

Comment: Such question belongs to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling your windows firewall and/or antivirus

Comment: it gives me the same think because in the config of firwal of  my win server 2012, the local port of server FTP is 21 but remote port is all.
as i said i try telnet 192.168.0.2 22 but it gives the same think

NB => on windows server where the ftp server is installed , when i test telnet 192.168.0.2 21 it gives me => 220 Microsoft FTP Service

Comment: try using putty + telnet

Comment: this is the error :

`C:\Users\admin>telnet 192.168.0.2 21
Connecting To 192.168.0.2... Could not open connection to the host. on port 21: Connect failed`

Comment: Try disabling your windows firewall and/or antivirus

Comment: thanx @alga tronic it works now by desabling firewall on the server

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you missed here is if you are using AWS Ec2 first you have to add Security Rules there.

[AWS Ec2 Security Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqIh3.png)

If the connection is the success you can see below message.
"220 Microsoft FTP Service"

you can check the connection via telnet.
Go to the command prompt and type "telnet [ServerIp] portNo"
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 21